# How do I get a random value from enums in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, enums, phaser-framework

I am tinkering with Phaser game engine. I have figured out how to color the sprite, so the next step is giving it a random color. How would I do that using an enum?

```
var colors = {
    RED: 0xff0000,
    GREEN: 0x00ff00,
    BLUE: 0x0000ff
}

logo.tint = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
```

Comment: `logo.tint=colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(colors).length)]`

Comment: colors[Math.random() % Object.keys(colors).length)]

Comment: @subdigit: sadly, i don't think that does what you want, and i know it doesn't do what the OP wants...

Comment: haha, oh right.  random is 0-1 isnt it...

Comment: how about store the colors in an array pick randomly using **game.rnd.weightedPick(myColorArray);**

Answer (score 13):

I just came to this problem today and able to get a random value by this:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(colors).length);
var randColorValue = colors[Object.keys(colors)[rand]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method I wrote in typescript that I used, remove types if you want to use with javascript.

```
function getRandomEnumValue<T>(anEnum: T): T[keyof T] {
  //save enums inside array
  const enumValues = Object.keys(anEnum) as Array<keyof T>; 
  
  //Generate a random index (max is array length)
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * enumValues.length);
  // get the random enum value
  
  const randomEnumKey = enumValues[randomIndex];
  return anEnum[randomEnumKey]; 
 // if you want to have the key than return randomEnumKey
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first instance your object as a Array

```
var colors =[
    {RED: 0xff0000},
    {GREEN: 0x00ff00},
    {BLUE: 0x0000ff}
];
```

Then, get a random position of the array.

```
colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
```